# Jest TypeError: this.props.fetchBitcoin is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

Im running a test with Jest for running at the test which is supposed to check if a function passed in through `props` using redux dispatches.

Here is the test:

```
  describe("when mounted", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      props.fetchBitcoin = mockFetchBitcoin;
      loot = mount(<Loot {...props} />);
    });

    it("fires the `fetchBitcoin()` from the props", () => {
      expect(mockFetchBitcoin).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

But when I run

`this.props.fetchBitcoin();` i get the following error

```
TypeError: this.props.fetchBitcoin is not a function

       9 |   }
      10 |   componentDidMount() {
    > 11 |     this.props.fetchBitcoin();
         |                ^
      12 |   }
      13 | }
```

The component which receives the props looks like:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchBitcoin } from "../actions/bitcoin";

export class Loot extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h3>Bitcoin balance:</h3>;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchBitcoin();
  }
}

export default connect(state => state, { fetchBitcoin })(Loot);
```

And the fetchBitcoin() looks like:

```
import { FETCH_BITCOIN } from "./constants";

export const fetchBitcoin = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => dispatch({ type: FETCH_BITCOIN, bitcoin: json }));
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you share the definition of ``mockFetchBitcoin``?

Comment: mockFetchBitcoin = jest.fn();

Comment: Have you tried referencing the mock instead of overriding the props key: like this   beforeEach(() => {
      loot = mount(<Loot {...props} fetchBitcoin={mockFetchBitcoin} />);
    });

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered with the same problem.

For me, the solutions was just add the if statement into React component like this:

```
export class Loot extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h3>Bitcoin balance:</h3>;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.fetchBitcoin) {

  }
}
```